# AWS Geolocation routing policy: how to go to a particular website?

Tags: amazon-route53

I wish to setup Route53 using **Geolocation routing policy**.

This means that a browser in Paris asking for "**www.mysite.com**" will go to the Berlin website, while a browser in Melbourne asking for the same "**www.mysite.com**" will go to the Sydney website.

But there is a need that when a user is in **Sydney** but he specifically wants to browse the **Berlin** website. How does he do it?